# Query Notification and Sql Dependancy, Check most, Read least

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqldependency, query-notifications

I have a 'C#' Application consuming a 'Sql Server 2012' database. I am using a `Sql Dependancy` object to watch the changes in an important table, using `Sql Server` `Query Notification` technology. I am currently watching for the following query :

```
SELECT Creditor, Description, AccountNo, Date, ID
FROM [dbo].[Acc_R1392]  
where AccountNo > 18000
and AccountType not in (1,2,5,7)
```

but this query result to a set of 10,000 (growing also) records, so each time a user DELETES, UPDATES or INSERTS (D/U/I) a record my application reads around 10,000 (growing also) records.

Briefly I want to detect changes on any records, so it won't help to filter last n records, on the other hand, it costs a lot to read all the records selected, is there somehow a way to detect D/U/I changes but read only the records which have been affected by the change?

Comment: I dont much abt Sql Dependancy but I'm wondering if using a trigger wont help to solve your requirement.

Comment: @Bayeni no trigger is not a good choice, triggers can play this role but you'll have a lot to implement yourself, while query notifications are ready meal.